# Bitcoin how to create a new account via RPC

Tags: exchange-server, blockchain, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, bitcoind

I am running docker container with bitcoin node and want to create a new account, but I can't find good documentation about bitcoin RPC methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create account using RPC run:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"method": "getnewaddress"}' rpcuser:rpcpassword@ip:port
```

Or, you can specify account and get this address assigned to new address:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"method": "getnewaddress", "params": ["billy"]}' rpcuser:rpcpassword@ip:port
```

I've found it here - [Bitcoin cryptocurrency node administration guide](https://www.openware.com/sdk/2.6/guides/cryptonodes/administration/bitcoind-cryptocurrency-node-administration-guide.html)

Also, if you running docker container don't forget to publish container's port (like `docker run -p "127.0.0.1:8332:8332"`)

Comment: Bitcoin addresses are not accounts

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Bitcoin address by running the following command:

```
bitcoin-cli getnewaddress
```

You can also do the same using cURL:

```
curl --user myrpcusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getnewaddress", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

More information [here](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getnewaddress.html)

Comment: Bitcoin addresses are not accounts